# ORACLE Error in loop, need to fill one variable per update

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, plsql

I have a cursor that retrieve the dates that I need to filter, then the loop where I get the values and one update with those variables

```
  DECLARE
      TYPE two_cols_rt IS RECORD
      (
      objectid_new BIDDATA.BID_GEN.OBJECTID%TYPE,
       bidid_new BIDDATA.BID_GEN.BIDID%TYPE
      );
    
    CURSOR c IS
        SELECT x.column_value startdate, x.column_value + 6/24 enddate
        FROM TABLE(
                   prod.date_utils(i_startdate     => date '2015-4-21'
                                                   ,i_enddate       => date '2015-4-21'
                                                   ,i_date_interval => 'HH')) x
        WHERE MOD( TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR(x.column_value, 'hh24') ), 6 ) = 0;
        
     TYPE  l_objects_t IS TABLE OF two_cols_rt;
     l_objects   l_objects_t;  
        
     BEGIN
        FOR rec IN c
        LOOP
            SELECT (SELECT prod.admin.find('UNIT'
                                               ,'unit'
                                               ,x.res_name
                                               ,TRUNC(sysdate, 'dd')
                                                ,'N')
            FROM dual) objectid_new
            ,x.BIDID  
            BULK COLLECT INTO l_objects
            FROM biddata.bid_gen x
            WHERE sced_time_stamp BETWEEN rec.startdate AND rec.enddate;  
         
            UPDATE BIDDATA.BID_GEN set objectid=l_objects.objectid_new
            WHERE bidid=l_objects.bidid_new;
          
                
        END LOOP;
    END;
```

But show me this error:

```
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 17
ORA-06512: at line 17
```

I dont need to return, I just need to update one row per all the ids that get the first select

Regards

Comment: The error seems to indicate that the `select` that populates `l_objectID_new` and `l_bidID` returns multiple rows.  If it returns multiple rows, what exactly do you want to do?  My guess would be that you want to define those local variables as collections rather than scalars, do a `bulk collect into` them, and then do a `forall` loop to iterate over the collection to update multiple rows in `bid_gen_rt_ercot`.  Or get rid of the `select` and the local variables and do the `update` directly.

Comment: hi Justin, that's true, but i am learning Oracle, i never used the bulk collect before.

Comment: Is this a homework question?  If so, what constructs are you allowed/ required to use?  Personally, I'd write this as a single `update` statement rather than using a loop or a separate `select` or any local variables.  But I don't know whether that would be a reasonable solution for you.

Comment: Hi, yes, I tried just an update but put me that select needs to put into clause statement. how do you do that?

Comment: I just used bulk to collect into, i updated the code but show me this error: ORA-06550: line 34, column 31:
PLS-00302: component 'BIDID_NEW' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 34, column 21:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "L_OBJECTS"."BIDID_NEW": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 33, column 9:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: If you want to change the local variables to a collection then like I said in my initial comment, you'd need to do a `forall` to iterate over the collection when doing the `update`.  That's the approach that involves the most code and it will be the slowest of the options and the additional code doesn't seem to make the code significantly easier to read so I'd opt for one of the two approaches I outline in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the loop, you can update multiple rows

```
   UPDATE BIDDATA.BID_GEN_RT_ERCOT x
      set objectid=prod.object_detail_admin.find('ERCOT_UNIT'
                                       ,'ERCOT'
                                       ,x.res_name
                                       ,trunc(sysdate, 'dd')
                                        ,'N')
    WHERE x.sced_time_stamp between rec.startdate and rec.enddate;
```

You could get rid of the loop entirely and just do

```
   UPDATE BIDDATA.BID_GEN_RT_ERCOT 
      set objectid=prod.object_detail_admin.find('ERCOT_UNIT'
                                       ,'ERCOT'
                                       ,res_name
                                       ,trunc(sysdate, 'dd')
                                        ,'N')
    WHERE exists( select 1
                    from table(
           prod.date_utils.get_listofdates_(i_startdate     => date '2015-4-21'
                                           ,i_enddate       => date '2015-4-21'
                                           ,i_date_interval => 'HH')) lod
                   where mod( to_number( to_char(lod.column_value, 'hh24') ), 6 ) = 0
                     and x.sced_time_stamp between lod.column_value 
                                               and lod.column_value + 6/24 );
```

If you want to keep the loop and the local variable and the separate `select` and `update` statements, you'd need to iterate over the collection in order to do the `update`

```
forall i in 1 .. l_objects.count
  update BIDDATA.BID_GEN_RT_ERCOT 
     set objectid=l_objects(i).objectid_new
   WHERE bidid=l_objects(i).bidid_new;
```

Comment: Hi Justin I just updated the code from the post using BULK TO COLLECT, but show me this error:  ORA-06550: line 34, column 31:
PLS-00302: component 'BIDID_NEW' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 34, column 21:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "L_OBJECTS"."BIDID_NEW": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 33, column 9:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored.  any idea?

Comment: @Webb - I added the third option.  That's going to be the least efficient option and will involve the most code.

Comment: @Webb Based on your other question that was recently deleted, you'll probably want to keep a loop-based approach or use a looped BULK-COLLECT-LIMIT-FORALL version add `dbms_lock.sleep(300);` or `dbms_session.sleep(300);` (in 19c) after each iteration. When you're trying to intentionally slow things down for replication, unfortunately you will often have to run code that is inefficient and more complicated. In fact, you may need another loop to restart the process, because if you keep the SELECT open for too long you'll hit an UNDO error.

Comment: @Webb And probably the reason your other question wasn't treated well is that people have a hard time understanding how much replication can ruin a reasonable solution unless they've seen it happen. When you ask these kinds of questions, or write this kind of code, it's helpful to add disclaimers up front explaining why the simple solution won't work.